# No match for operator "==" for nonmember operator overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
    private: int cost{};
    public: 
    Test(int value): cost{value}{}
    int GetCost() const{return cost;}
    
    bool operator >(const Test& rhs) const noexcept {return GetCost() > rhs.GetCost();}
    bool operator>=(const Test& rhs) const noexcept {return (*this > rhs) || (*this == rhs;)}
    
};


bool operator==(const Test& a, const Test& b) noexcept
{
    return a.GetCost() == b.GetCost();
}

int main()
{
    cout<< (Test{2} >= Test{3});

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error for the code.

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const Test’ and ‘const Test’)
     bool operator>=(const Test& rhs) const noexcept {return *this == rhs;}
```

What is the problem here? Is it not possible to mix member and non-member operator overloads?

Comment: Order matters! When you use the `==` operator, it has not been declared yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should also overload operator `==` in `Test` class.

```
class Test{
private: 
    int cost{};
public: 
    Test(int value): cost{value}{}
    int GetCost() const{return cost;}


    bool operator==(const Test& rhs) const noexcept {return GetCost() == rhs.GetCost();}
    bool operator >(const Test& rhs) const noexcept {return GetCost() > rhs.GetCost();}
    bool operator>=(const Test& rhs) const noexcept {return (*this > rhs) || (*this == rhs);}

};
```

So you can use it in your overloading and member functions like `operator>=`.
for more work you can do this:

```
bool operator==(const Test& a, const int& b) noexcept
{
    return a.GetCost() == b;
}
```

And This:

```
bool operator==(const int& a, const Test& b) noexcept
{
    return a == b.GetCost();
}
```

By doing so you can even use == as follows:

```
cout<< (Test{3} == 3);
cout<< (2 == Test{3});
```